# Outcome of pure python script changes with each execution despite not having any randomness

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to resolve this kata https://www.codewars.com/kata/5b86a6d7a4dcc13cd900000b

My code doesn't contain any randomness at all, and the only imports I use are from built-in packages. I noticed something strange. When I run it, I either get
None  # no solution for the problem
or
((('NNE',), ('EES',)), ('SS',))  # solution found (I know it's incorrect, but that's not the point right now)
and I don't change anything in the code in the meantime.

I use Python 3.10 and
PyCharm 2023.1 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-231.8109.197, built on March 29, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+10-b829.5 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2042M
Cores: 16

My code is still in writing, so sorry for the spaghetti.

```
import logging
from copy import deepcopy
from typing import Union


class Cell:
    def __init__(self, walls: int = None, north: bool = None, south: bool = None, west: bool = None, east: bool = None,
                 from_walls: bool = True):
        if from_walls:
            if walls is None or not isinstance(walls, int):
                raise ValueError("Walls must be int")
            walls = walls % 16
            self.walls = walls
            self.north, self.west, self.south, self.east = [True if x == '1' else False for x in
                                                            list(bin(self.walls).replace("0b", "").zfill(4))]
        else:
            if north is None or south is None or west is None or east is None:
                raise ValueError("Provide boolean value for all walls")
            self.north, self.west, self.south, self.east = north, west, south, east
            self.walls = 8 * self.north + 4 * self.west + 2 * self.south + 1 * self.east

    def rotate(self):
        self.walls = self.walls * 2 if self.walls * 2 < 16 else (self.walls * 2) - 16 + 1
        self.north, self.west, self.south, self.east = [True if x == '1' else False for x in
                                                        list(bin(self.walls).replace("0b", "").zfill(4))]
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return f"N: {self.north}, W: {self.west}, S: {self.south}, E: {self.east}"

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"N: {self.north}, W: {self.west}, S: {self.south}, E: {self.east}"


def get_starting_point(test):
    for index, row in enumerate(test):
        if row[0] == 'B':
            return (index, 0)


def get_finishing_point(test):
    for index, row in enumerate(test):
        if row[-1] == 'X':
            return (index, len(test[0]) - 1)


def get_possible_actions(test: Union[tuple, list], cell_coordinates: tuple) -> object:
    width, height = len(test[0]), len(test)
    north, west, south, east = [True] * 4
    if cell_coordinates[0] == 0:
        north = False
    if cell_coordinates[0] == height - 1:
        south = False
    if cell_coordinates[1] == 0:
        west = False
    if cell_coordinates[1] == width - 1:
        east = False
    north_open, west_open, south_open, east_open = [False] * 4
    # the ifs are there to get rid of exceptions with IndexError "out of range"
    if north:
        north_open = not test[cell_coordinates[0]][cell_coordinates[1]].north and not test[cell_coordinates[0] - 1][
            cell_coordinates[1]].south
    if south:
        south_open = not test[cell_coordinates[0]][cell_coordinates[1]].south and not test[cell_coordinates[0] + 1][
            cell_coordinates[1]].north
    if west:
        west_open = not test[cell_coordinates[0]][cell_coordinates[1]].west and not test[cell_coordinates[0]][
            cell_coordinates[1] - 1].east
    if east:
        east_open = not test[cell_coordinates[0]][cell_coordinates[1]].east and not test[cell_coordinates[0]][
            cell_coordinates[1] + 1].west

    north = north and north_open
    south = south and south_open
    west = west and west_open
    east = east and east_open

    output = set()
    if north:
        output.add('N')
    if south:
        output.add('S')
    if west:
        output.add('W')
    if east:
        output.add('E')

    return output


def get_all_possible_moves(possible_actions, maze_cells, start):
    # find all possible ways
    if start not in possible_actions.keys():
        possible_actions[start] = get_possible_actions(maze_cells, cell_coordinates=start)

    neighbor_coords = {
        "N": (start[0] - 1, start[1]),
        "S": (start[0] + 1, start[1]),
        "E": (start[0], start[1] + 1),
        "W": (start[0], start[1] - 1),
    }
    for possible_move_of_parent in possible_actions[start]:
        # todo make sure no number in coords is negative - that's legal when slicing, but incorrect in solution
        if neighbor_coords[possible_move_of_parent] not in possible_actions.keys():
            possible_actions[
                neighbor_coords[possible_move_of_parent]
            ] = get_possible_actions(
                maze_cells,
                neighbor_coords[possible_move_of_parent]
            )
            possible_actions = {
                **get_all_possible_moves(possible_actions, maze_cells, neighbor_coords[possible_move_of_parent]),
                **possible_actions
            }

    return possible_actions


def get_maze_paths(paths, possible_moves: dict, already_considered_coords: set, start: tuple) -> dict:
    if start in already_considered_coords:
        return paths
    already_considered_coords.add(start)
    neighbor_coords_per_direction = {
        "N": (start[0] - 1, start[1]),
        "S": (start[0] + 1, start[1]),
        "E": (start[0], start[1] + 1),
        "W": (start[0], start[1] - 1),
    }
    # clean up - if in "aleardy_considered_coords" - remove from possible neighbors
    neighbor_coords_per_direction = {
        key: value for key, value in neighbor_coords_per_direction.items() if value not in already_considered_coords
    }
    # recursively check all chains of neighbors, add the translation (N,E,W,S) to the output string,
    for direction, neighbor_coords in neighbor_coords_per_direction.items():
        if neighbor_coords in possible_moves.keys():
            paths[neighbor_coords] += paths[start] + direction
            paths = get_maze_paths(paths, possible_moves, already_considered_coords, start=neighbor_coords)

    return paths


def get_paths(possible_moves, start):
    paths = {
        key: '' for key, _ in possible_moves.items()
    }
    already_considered_coords = set()
    paths = get_maze_paths(paths, possible_moves, already_considered_coords, start)
    return paths


def get_paths_per_coord(test_cells, start_point):
    possible_actions = {}
    possible_moves = get_all_possible_moves(possible_actions=possible_actions, maze_cells=test_cells, start=start_point)
    paths = get_paths(
        possible_moves=possible_moves,
        start=start_point
    )
    return paths


class Maze:
    def __init__(self, input_tuple_of_tuples: tuple):
        self.width, self.height = len(input_tuple_of_tuples[0]), len(input_tuple_of_tuples)
        for row in input_tuple_of_tuples:
            assert len(row) == self.width

        maze = []
        for row in input_tuple_of_tuples:
            test_cells_row = [Cell(x) if isinstance(x, int) else Cell(0) for x in row]
            maze.append(test_cells_row)
        self.maze = maze
        self.start_point = get_starting_point(input_tuple_of_tuples)
        self.end_point = get_finishing_point(input_tuple_of_tuples)

    def rotate_maze(self):
        for row in self.maze:
            for cell in row:
                cell.rotate()
        return self.maze


def solution(test):
    maze = Maze(
        input_tuple_of_tuples=test
    )

    paths = get_paths_per_coord(maze.maze, maze.start_point)
    global_paths = {key:(value,) for key,value in deepcopy(paths).items()}
    number_of_discovered_cells = []
    for iteration in range(1,1000):
        number_of_discovered_cells.append(len(global_paths.keys()))
        # if in four rotations it didn't enlarge the pool of known paths, there is no way to reach X
        if iteration > 4:
            if max(number_of_discovered_cells[-4:]) == number_of_discovered_cells[-4]:
                return None
        # rotate maze, check again
        maze.rotate_maze()
        logging.debug("Rotating")
        for coord, path in paths.items():
            new_paths = get_paths_per_coord(maze.maze, coord)

            for new_coord, new_path in new_paths.items():
                previous_steps = global_paths[coord]
                new_step = new_path if isinstance(new_path, tuple) else (new_path,)
                new_path_tuple = (previous_steps, new_step)
                if new_coord not in global_paths.keys():
                    global_paths[new_coord] = new_path_tuple
        if maze.end_point in global_paths.keys():
            return global_paths[maze.end_point]
        paths = new_paths


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(
        solution(
            test=(
                (4, 2, 5, 4),
                (4, 15, 11, 1),
                ('B', 9, 6, 8),
                (12, 7, 7, 'X')
            )
        )
    )
```

I tried to update from python 3.7 to 3.10 - now None happens more frequently, but occasionally I get ((('NNE',), ('EES',)), ('SS',)).

I'm expecting the output to be repeatable. Can someone reproduce that? EDIT: What is the reason why it's not repeatable?

Comment: What's the first thing in that too long code that changes?

Comment: Thanks Tom for pointing that out! Unfortunately renaming it didn't change the outcome, it's still not repeatable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the reason why it's not repeatable?

You use sets of strings, which have arbitrary randomized order due to Python's [string hashing randomization](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-R).

Already `print({'N', 'E'})` randomly prints either `{'N', 'E'}` or `{'E', 'N'}`.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. Although it doesn't quite explain why the problem happens - I basically use these sets as iteration objects, and the order in which the elements of the set are returned doesn't play a role in my code.

Comment: @wtarnawski So if you let's say change `return output` to `return sorted(output)` so that the order is deterministic, you still get different results?

Comment: @wtarnawski With `return sorted(output)` I always get `((('NNE',), ('EES',)), ('SS',))`, and with `return sorted(output, reverse=True)` I always get `None`.

Comment: Mind blown! Thank you